# Subsequence with maximum sum in array of ints

Tags: algorithm, arrays, language-agnostic

Given an array of integers, how can you find two indices, i and j, such that the sum of the elements in the subarray starting and ending at the indices is maximized, **in linear time**?

Comment: You mean - between the indices?

Comment: `i = 0` and `j = array.length-1` :)

Comment: @Bart, who said that array elements are greater than zero?

Comment: The answers so far seem to assume you meant "sum of the elements from index i to index j" but as far as I see you only ask for the sum of elements i and j, care to elaborate? (Also can i == j? the answer would be `2 * max(array values)` in that case :-) )

Comment: sum of the elements in between. and there are negative elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from my copy of [programming pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657880):

```
maxsofar = 0
maxendinghere = 0
for i = [0, n)
    /* invariant: maxendinghere and maxsofar are accurate
       are accurate for x[0..i-1] */
    maxendinghere = max(maxendinghere + x[i], 0)
    maxsofar = max(maxsofar, maxendinghere)
```

Comment: A correct and a succinct one. But it took you the same time to copy it down as for me to devise it :)

Comment: Soooo, what's `i` and `j` then?

Comment: To get start and end of the sequence you just need to remember the proper i(ndex into the array) depending on what you choose in the two max statements.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is actually called **Kadane's algorithm**; discovered (or invented, whichever floats your boat) in 1984 by Jay Kadane of Carnegie-Mellon. It is the only known linear time algorithm to solve this problem, which is more generally known as the [**Maximum Subarray Problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

Comment: wont work when all the values of the input array are negative

Comment: @alien very true, to fix for that you'd use something like INT_MIN (depending on your environment) as initial values for maxsofar, maxendinghere, and the 0 in the recomputation of maxendinghere.

Comment: @jillesdewit : yes. or scan through input once. Before starting and if all are negative, make them positive.

Comment: @alien given that we are going for the fastest solution this might not be optimal. Also, is you flip the sign you are also effectively looking for the minumum sum (in the original array) rather than the maximum sum.

Comment: @jillesdewit, the question is about maximum subsequence , not maximum subarray.

Comment: @hareendrareddy It might be my non-native english, but what is the difference between "subsequence" and "subarray" in this context?

Comment: @jillesdewit , in subsequence the elements are not necessarily contiguous. for eg: in array [1,2,3,4,5]   [2,3,4] is sub array and [1,3,5] is a subsequence

Comment: @hareendrareddy interesting, I didn't know. However, I think the question is about subarray then, not subsequence. The original asker clarified this in his last comment to the question.

Answer (score 11):

Simple.  Assume you're given the array `a`.  First, you calculate the array `s`, where `s[i] = a[0]+a[1]+...+a[i]`.  You can do it in linear time:

```
s[0]=a[0];
for (i=1;i<N;i++) s[i]=s[i-1]+a[i];
```

Now, the sum `a[i]+a[i+1]+..+a[j]` is equal to `s[j]-s[i-1]`.  For a fixed `j`, to maximize the value of this difference, you should find *a minimal `s[i-1]` in range of `0..(j-1)`*.

Imagine a usual algorithm to find minimal value in the array.

```
min = x[0];
for (j=1; j<N; j++)
  if (x[j] < min)
    min = x[j];
```

You iterate and compare each array element to `min`... But on each iteration this `min` is the lowest value in array, where index range is of `0..j`!  And that's what we're looking for!

```
global_max = a[0];
max_i = max_j = 0;
local_min_index = 0;
for (j=1; j<N; j++){
  // here local_min is the lowest value of s[i], where 0<=i<j
  if (s[j] - s[local_min_index] > global_max) {
     global_max = s[j] - s[local_min_index]
     //update indices
     max_i = local_min_index + 1;
     max_j = j;
  }
  //update local_min_index for next iteration
  if (s[j]<local_min){
    local_min = s[j];
    // update indices
    local_min_index = j;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to an anonymous user for his lengthy post explaining the bugs in the code.  I got rid of them, except for the failure if `N==0`.

Answer (score 1):

this python code returns the bounds of the sequence.  in terms of the original question, `i=bestlo`, `j=besthi-1`.

```
#
# given a sequence X of signed integers,
# find a contiguous subsequence that has maximal sum.
# return the lo and hi indices that bound the subsequence.
# the subsequence is X[lo:hi] (exclusive of hi).
#
def max_subseq(X):
    #
    # initialize vars to establish invariants.
    # 1: best subseq so far is [bestlo..besthi), and bestsum is its sum
    # 2: cur subseq is [curlo..curhi), and cursum is its sum
    #
    bestlo,besthi,bestsum  =  0,0,0
    curlo,curhi,cursum  =  0,0,0
    for i in xrange(len(X)):
        # extend current subseq and update vars
        curhi = i+1
        cursum += X[i]
        if cursum <= 0:
            #
            # the current subseq went under water,
            # so it can't be usefully extended.
            # start fresh at next index.
            #
            curlo = curhi
            cursum = 0
        elif cursum > bestsum:
            # adopt current subseq as the new best
            bestlo,besthi,bestsum  =  curlo,curhi,cursum

    return (bestlo,besthi)
```

and here are some doctest examples that this code passes.

```
    r'''
    doctest examples:
    >>> print max_subseq([])
    (0, 0)
    >>> print max_subseq([10])
    (0, 1)
    >>> print max_subseq([-1])
    (0, 0)
    >>> print max_subseq(xrange(5))
    (1, 5)
    >>> print max_subseq([-1, 1, -1])
    (1, 2)
    >>> print max_subseq([-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 2, -1])
    (6, 8)
    >>> print max_subseq([-2, 11, -4, 13, -5, -2])
    (1, 4)
    >>> print max_subseq([4, -3, 5, -2, -1, 2, 6,-4])
    (0, 7)
    '''
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually need Kadane's algorithm modification that remembers lower and upper bounds for the sub-array, here's C++11 code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::pair<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator> SubSeq;

SubSeq getMaxSubSeq(std::vector<int> &arr) {
    SubSeq maxSequence{arr.begin(), arr.begin()};
    auto tmpBegin = arr.begin();
    int maxEndingHere = 0;
    int maxSoFar = 0;

    for(auto it = arr.begin(); it < arr.end(); ++it) {
        int currentSum = maxEndingHere + *it;

        if(currentSum > 0) {
            if(maxEndingHere == 0) {
                tmpBegin = it;
            }
            maxEndingHere = currentSum;
        } else {
            maxEndingHere = 0;
        }

        if(maxEndingHere > maxSoFar) {
            maxSoFar = maxEndingHere;
            maxSequence.first = tmpBegin;
            maxSequence.second = it + 1;
        }
    }

    return maxSequence;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr{-1, 2, 90, -50, 150, -300, 56, 12};

    auto seq = getMaxSubSeq(arr);
    while(seq.first != seq.second) {
        std::cout << *(seq.first) << " ";
        ++(seq.first);
    }

    return 0;
}
```