# Find the subsequence with largest sum of elements in an array

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I recently interviewed with a company and they asked me to write an algorithm that finds the subsequence with largest sum of elements in an array. The elements in the array can be negative. Is there a O(n) solution for it? Any good solutions are very much appreciated.

Comment: did you mean **longest** subsequence? Also is it longest increasing ?

Comment: What do you mean by "largest subsequance"? -- Oh, OK. You probably mean: find the subsequence with the largest sum of elements.

Comment: do you mean longest sequence of number such that sum of those numbers is largest in an array?

Comment: @jsshah yes. its subsequence with largest sum of elements

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706529/subsequence-with-maximum-sum-in-array-of-ints

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want the largest sum of sequential numbers then something like this might work:

```
$cur = $max = 0;
foreach ($seq as $n)
{
  $cur += $n;
  if ($cur < 0) $cur = 0;
  if ($cur > $max) $max = $cur;
}
```

That's just off the top of my head, but it seems right. (Ignoring that it assumes 0 is the answer for empty and all negative sets.)

Edit:

If you also want the sequence position:

```
$cur = $max = 0;
$cur_i = $max_i = 0; 
$max_j = 1;

foreach ($seq as $i => $n)
{
  $cur += $n;
  if ($cur > $max)
  {
    $max = $cur;
    if ($cur_i != $max_i)
    {
      $max_i = $cur_i;
      $max_j = $max_i + 1;
    }
    else
    {
      $max_j = $i + 1;
    }
  }

  if ($cur < 0)
  {
    $cur = 0;
    $cur_i = $i + 1;
  }
}

var_dump(array_slice($seq, $max_i, $max_j - $max_i), $max);
```

There might be a more concise way to do it. Again, it has the same assumptions (at least one positive integer). Also, it only finds the first biggest sequence.

Edit: changed it to use `max_j` (exclusive) instead of `max_len`.

Comment: This is not what he is looking for. He asked for a sub sequence which has the maximum sum. You gave him the contiguous sub-sequence with max. sum. In sub-sequence the number are not necessarily contiguous.

Comment: @Kapil D, my answer very clearly starts off by saying what it is answering. Was it what his interviewers were looking for? We'll never know. It obviously is what he was looking for, as he accepted it. (If he really wanted a subsequence with the largest sum, the answer is trivial: remove all negative numbers.)

Comment: Yeah, I know you wrote it for sequential number. May be the person who wrote the question was not clear. I like your solution to the max sequence problem.

Answer (score 14):

If you mean longest increasing subsequence, see **codaddict**'s answer.

If on the other hand you mean finding the **sub array with maximum sum** (makes sense only with negative values), then there is an elegant, dynamic programming style linear time solution:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

Comment: Good link. It appears that my answer was just an implementation of that algorithm.

Comment: @konforce: exactly. You also need to record the start/end positions for returning the subarray itself, of course. +1.

Comment: +1 … Finding this algorithm is a routine exercise in most intro CS courses (CS 101 or CS 102).

Comment: well since only subsequence with maximum sum is required, can't it work like this :
1. sort the array first in decreasing order.
2. keep on adding from the first element till you encounter a negative value. output the sum till now and you are done....

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {-11,-2,3,-1,2,-9,-4,-5,-2, -3};
    int cur = arr[0] >= 0? arr[0] : 0, max = arr[0];
    int start = 0, end = 0;
    int i,j = cur == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    printf("Cur\tMax\tStart\tEnd\n");
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",cur,max,start,end);
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        cur += arr[i];
        if (cur > max) {
            max = cur;
            end = i;
            if (j > start) start = j;
        }     
        if (cur < 0) {
            cur = 0;
            j = i+1;
        }
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",cur,max,start,end);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean ***longest increasing subsequence***.

There is no `O(n)` solution for that.

A very naive solution would be to create a duplicate array, sort it in `O(NlogN)` and then find the `LCS` of the sorted array and original array which takes `O(N^2)`.

There also is a direct DP based solution similar to `LCS` which also takes `O(N^2)`, which you can see [here](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Longest_Increasing_Subsequence#Dynamic_Programming).

But if you meant longest increasing sequence (consecutive). This can be done in `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void longsub(int a[], int len)  {

        int localsum = INT_MIN;
        int globalsum = INT_MIN;
        int startindex = 0,i=0;
        int stopindex = 0;
        int localstart = 0;

        for (i=0; i < len; i++) {
                if (localsum + a[i] < a[i]) {
                        localsum = a[i];
                        localstart = i;
                }
                else {
                        localsum += a[i];
                }

                if (localsum > globalsum) {
                        startindex = localstart;
                        globalsum =  localsum;
                        stopindex = i;
                }

        }

        printf ("The begin and end indices are %d -> %d (%d).\n",startindex, stopindex, globalsum);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved two different ways.

The first approach is have two variables called `sum` and `MaxSum`.

1. We will keep on adding values to the sum and will compare with the MaxSum, if the value for the sum is greater than the MaxSum - will assign sum value to the MaxSum
2. If during the process the value for the sum goes below 0, we will reset the sum and will start adding new number from the next index on-wards. 
   The sample code for the above solution is provided as below:

   ```
   private static void FindMaxSum(int[] array)
   {
       int sum = 0;
       int MaxSum = 0;

       for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
       {
           sum += array[i];

           if (sum > MaxSum)
           {
               MaxSum = sum;
           }
           else if (sum < 0)
           {
               sum = 0;
           }
       }
       Console.WriteLine("Maximum sum is: " + MaxSum);
   }
   ```

The second approach to solve this problem is that we will go through each and every element in an array. We will have same 2 variables of sum and MaxSum.

1. First we will compare the addition of sum with the next array element and the sum itself. Who ever is greater - that value will be stored in the sum variable.
2. Next we will compare the values of sum and MaxSum and whoever has greater value - we will save that value in the MaxSum variable.
   The sample code is as mentioned below:

   ```
   private static void FindMaxSum(int[] array)
   {
       int sum = array[0], Maxsum = array[0];

       for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
       {
           sum = Max(sum + array[i], array[i]);
           Maxsum = Max(sum, Maxsum);               
       }

       Console.WriteLine("Maximum sum is: " + Maxsum);
   }

   private static int Max(int a, int b)
   {
       return a > b ? a : b;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Since, we need to find the Maximum Sub-sequence Sum, We can:

1. Sort the Array In descending order.
2. Take two variable `sum` and `maxSum`.
3. Run a for loop till `length n`.
4. Update `maxSum` when `sum > maxSum`.

The `Java` Code Snippet will be something line this:

```
Arrays.sort(a, Collections.reverseOrder());
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
 sum = sum + a[i];
     if (sum > maxSum) 
         maxSum = sum;
}
System.out.println(maxSum);
```

Time Complexity: O(nlogn)

Answer (score -1):

C function looks like this:

```
int largest(int arr[], int length)
{
  int sum= arr[0];
  int tempsum=0;
  for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
     tempsum+=arr[i];
     if(tempsum>sum)
        sum=tempsum;
     if(tempsum<0)
        tempsum=0;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking what is a contiguous subsequence for which the sum is maximum, I have found 4 algos so far:-

1. Brute-force: Find all possible sums using nested loops and keep updating the maxSum if you find a sum greater than previous set value of maxSum. The time complexity is O(n^2)
2. Dynamic Programming Solution: This is a remarkably elegant solution which I found on StackOverflow itself - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649869/2461567v -
   Time complexity : O(n), 
   Space complexity : O(n)
3. DP without memory - Kadane Algorithm -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem -
   Time complexity : O(n), Space complexity : O(1)
4. Divide and Conquer Solution - http://eecs.wsu.edu/~nroy/courses/CptS223/notes/MaxSubsequenceSum.pdf
   Time complexity : O(nlgn)