# How to Implement MaxSubArray in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to develop **Max Sub Array Problem** in C#

And my code is

```
try
        {
            int[] Values = { 9, 1, 4, 15, -5, -41, -8, 78, 145, 14 };//Will be executed once '1'


            int StartIndex = 0;//Will be executed once '1'
            double Sum = 0;//Will be executed once '1'
            double Temp = 0;//Will be executed once '1'
            double Max = 0;//Will be executed once '1'

            do
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < Values.Length; i++)//1+(N+1)+N
                {
                    Sum = Values[StartIndex];

                    if (StartIndex < i)
                    {
                        for (int j = StartIndex+1; j <= i; j++)
                        {
                            Sum += Values[j];
                        }

                        if (Sum > Temp)
                        {
                            Max = Sum;
                            Temp = Sum;
                        }
                    }
                }
                StartIndex++;
            } while (StartIndex<Values.Length);


            MessageBox.Show("The Max Value is " + Max);



        }
        catch { }
```

I would like to know if this is the best approach to solve this algorithm as I am trying to minimize the time complexity

Thank you all for your time

Comment: It might be better to post your question on code review - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't see any advanced operations in your code.. Is there any reason why you put it in a try block?

Answer (score 1):

Divide-and-Conquer realization with O(N*logN) complexity was described in [Inroduction to Algorithms: CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), Chapter 4 Divide-and-Conquer 4.1 The maximum-subarray problem. C# port [from](http://la0t1.blogspot.ru/2011/07/maxmimum-subarray-problem.html).

```
 class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] values = { 9, 1, 4, 15, -5, -41, -8, 78, 145, 14 };
        Console.WriteLine(FindMaxSubarray(values, 0, values.Length - 1));
    }

    public struct MaxSubArray {
        public int Low;
        public int High;
        public int Sum;

        public override string ToString() {
            return String.Format("From: {0} To: {1} Sum: {2}", Low, High, Sum);
        }
    }

    private static MaxSubArray FindMaxSubarray(int[] a, int low, int high) {
        var res = new MaxSubArray {
            Low = low,
            High = high,
            Sum = a[low]
        };
        if (low == high) return res;

        var mid = (low + high) / 2;
        var leftSubarray = FindMaxSubarray(a, low, mid);
        var rightSubarray = FindMaxSubarray(a, mid + 1, high);
        var crossingSubarray = FindMaxCrossingSubarray(a, low, mid, high);

        if (leftSubarray.Sum >= rightSubarray.Sum &&
            leftSubarray.Sum >= crossingSubarray.Sum)
            return leftSubarray;
        if (rightSubarray.Sum >= leftSubarray.Sum &&
                 rightSubarray.Sum >= crossingSubarray.Sum)
            return rightSubarray;
        return crossingSubarray;
    }

    private static MaxSubArray FindMaxCrossingSubarray(int[] a, int low, int mid, int high) {
        var maxLeft = 0;
        var maxRight = 0;

        var leftSubarraySum = Int32.MinValue;
        var rightSubarraySum = Int32.MinValue;

        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = mid; i >= low; i--) {
            sum += a[i];
            if (sum <= leftSubarraySum) continue;
            leftSubarraySum = sum;
            maxLeft = i;
        }

        sum = 0;
        for (var j = mid + 1; j <= high; j++) {
            sum += a[j];
            if (sum <= rightSubarraySum) continue;
            rightSubarraySum = sum;
            maxRight = j;
        }

        return new MaxSubArray {
            Low = maxLeft,
            High = maxRight,
            Sum = leftSubarraySum + rightSubarraySum
        };

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

time complexity of your code is `O(n^3)`, but you can improve it with two [renovations](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-14-maximum-sum-increasing-subsequence/) and change it to `O(N^2)`. but there is a better [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649845/how-can-i-find-the-maximum-sum-of-a-sub-sequence-using-dynamic-programming) that designed by the dynamic programming.

[this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CFsQtwIwBQ&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siaRlAtip9I&ei=O9hCUZfkE-uS7AbFzYG4Cw&usg=AFQjCNF6fyKfXDeOeQEXgxGSpLzssQqGrA&bvm=bv.43828540,d.ZGU) solution solve it in matrix array.
Note: maximum default value should be set to the infinite negative.

This is a code from the wiki:

A variation of the problem that does not allow zero-length subarrays to be returned in the case that the entire array consists of negative numbers can be solved with the following code, expressed here in C++ Programming Language.

```
int sequence(std::vector<int>& numbers)
{
        // Initialize variables here
        int max_so_far  = numbers[0], max_ending_here = numbers[0];
        size_t begin = 0;
        size_t begin_temp = 0;
        size_t end = 0;
        // Find sequence by looping through
        for(size_t i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++)
        {
                // calculate max_ending_here
                if(max_ending_here < 0)
                {
                        max_ending_here = numbers[i];
                        begin_temp = i;
                }
                else
                {
                        max_ending_here += numbers[i];
                }
                // calculate max_so_far
                if(max_ending_here > max_so_far )
                {
                        max_so_far  = max_ending_here;
                        begin = begin_temp;
                        end = i;
                }
        }
        return max_so_far ;
}
```

Comment: thank @MatthewWatson .i attached this link into algorithm word

Comment: Cool - I removed my now-redundant comment. :) Incidentally, did you notice that the value of `begin` and `end` is never used? Not really the best code to have up on Wikipedia!

Comment: begin = begin_temp;
                        end = i; ???

Answer (score 1):

There's an O(N) algorithm presented here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

It doesn't actually give you the subarray, just the maximal value of the subarray.

**Note** the important restriction that the input array must contain at least one positive (nonzero) number.

I have modified it to return the range as well as the maximal value:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //int[] numbers = new[] { -2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4 };
            //int[] numbers = new[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

            int[] numbers = new[] {9, 1, 4, 15, -5, -41, -8, 78, 145, 14};

            var result = FindMaximumSubarray(numbers);

            Console.WriteLine("Range = {0}..{1}, Value = {2}", result.StartIndex, result.EndIndex, result.Value);
        }

        public static MaximumSubarray FindMaximumSubarray(int[] numbers)
        {
            int maxSoFar = numbers[0];
            int maxEndingHere = numbers[0];
            int begin = 0;
            int startIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (maxEndingHere < 0)
                {
                    maxEndingHere = numbers[i];
                    begin = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    maxEndingHere += numbers[i];
                }

                if (maxEndingHere > maxSoFar)
                {
                    startIndex = begin;
                    endIndex = i;
                    maxSoFar = maxEndingHere;
                }
            }

            return new MaximumSubarray
            {
                StartIndex = startIndex,
                EndIndex = endIndex,
                Value = maxSoFar
            };
        }

        public struct MaximumSubarray
        {
            public int StartIndex;
            public int EndIndex;
            public int Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            int[] Values = { 9, 1, 4, 15, -5, -41, -8, 78, 145, 14 };//Will be executed once '1'

            int max_ending_here = 0;
            int max_so_far = 0;

            foreach(int x in Values)
            {
                max_ending_here = Math.Max(0, max_ending_here + x);
                max_so_far = Math.Max(max_so_far, max_ending_here);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The Max Value is " + max_so_far);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

[Reference Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)